# overriding child method with parent method in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

suppose I have a child component

save-button.vue

```
<template>
<!--some code like label/div-->
<button @click="save">Save</button>
<!--some code like label/div-->
</template>
<script>
export default{
  methods:{
    save(){
      //some code here
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

parent.vue

```
<save-button/>
...
<script>
export default{
  methods:{
    save(){
      //some codes
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now in the parent component, I need to override the save function in save-button.vue with the save function in parent.vue. How should I do it? The save function in save-button.vue is shared by a lot of other components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function as a non-required prop.

Parent

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">Using Parent:
    <SaveButton :save="save"/>Using Default:
    <SaveButton/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SaveButton from "./components/SaveButton";

export default {
  components: {
    SaveButton
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      console.log("Save from Parent !");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="saveClicked">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    save: {
      type: Function,
      default: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveClicked() {
      if (this.save) {
        this.save();
        return;
      }
      console.log("Save from the Child !");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```